# Issue with margin-top / padding-top of div. Display-block etc. not working

Tags: css, html

I'm a little new to coding and I've found these boards really helpful over the last few weeks but I've come across a problem that other posts couldn't help me with, so here goes:

I have a number of divs within one rectangle div, 880px across. The left aligned divs are working perfectly but the floated right div, a video 560px across called #shopvid_2013_01 just won't line up right.

I want it so that the #shopvid_2013_01 div lines up exactly beside the #shop_13_01 div, but instead when I preview it on Firefox it seems to be right underneath another div I have and won't move no matter what margin-top or padding-top I use. I tried adding display:block and overflow:hidden as I read on other posts that might help, but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated!

I've included my relevant html and css:

HTML

```
<div id="shop_13">    
    <div id="shop_13_01">
        <div id="shop_13_text_01">
            <div id="shop_smlheading">
                <p><b>West Cork Rally 2013</b></p>
            </div>
            <div id="shop_p_13">
                <p>Our highlights video from a cracking weekend in Clonakilty.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="buy_shop_01">
                <form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post"    target="_top">
                    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
                    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="6D49SM33FHD8U">
                    <input type="image" src="01 Images/buy_now_price.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="Buy Now">
                    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif"  width="1" height="1">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="shopvid_2013_01">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ozXu2-Zf5B0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#shop_13 {
    width:880px;    
}

#shop_13_01 {
    width: 320px;
    height:315px;
    margin:30px 0 0 0;
    background-color:#E9E9E9;
    float:left;
}

#shop_13_text_01 {
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
    width:240px;
    font-size:13px;
    line-height:1.4em;
}

#shop_smlheading {
    padding: 5px 0 0 20px;
    font-size:15px;
}

#shop_p_13 {
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
    width:240px;
    font-size:13px;
    line-height:1.4em;
    margin: -15px 0 0 20px;
    float:left;
}

#buy_shop_01 {
    padding: 100px 0 0 0;
    float:left;
}

#shopvid_2013_01 {
    width: 560px;
    height:315px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 30px;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are referencing `shopvid_2013_01` as an ID rather than a CLASS. Try this:

```
.shopvid_2013_01 {
  width: 560px;
  height:315px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display:block;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gGtPK/

Comment: Wow you're right, I'm embarrassed! Thanks so much it's lining up perfect now!